# Need help to understand the following derivation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Recently, I have been studying the Phugoid motion model. While following the derivation on [nbViewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/lessons/01_phugoid/01_01_Phugoid_Theory.ipynb), I became quite confused while going from Eq. $11$ to Eq. $12$. At this point, the author has multiplied both sides of the equation $\frac{1}{R}=-\sin\theta \frac{d\theta}{dz}$ with $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}$ and came up with the expression: $$\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2z_{t}}-\frac{\cos\theta}{2\sqrt{z}}=\frac{\sqrt{z}}{R}.$$ I can not figure out, how the author has come up with this derivation. I shall be very grateful, if someone just show me how it happened like this.

Let me know any other information required.
Regards

Comment: looks like he integrated somhow over dz and $dθ$.... do you have any information about the possible intervall?

Comment: I don't know Borge... I was looking at this step for hours and going nowhere...

Comment: do you know how $z_t$ is defined? and where it comes from? (my guess: this is one of the Integral limits)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple you get there from eq9: $\frac{z}{zt}−\cos θ=\frac{2z}{R}$.... eq 10 and 11 are for later use......